# Visual Studio crash when clicking on Debug in the menu bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2010 is crashing in a very strange way. This is how it happens:

1. Start Visual Studio 2010
2. Open the project
3. Start debugging
4. Click on the Debug menu in the menu bar
5. **Crash**

If I do the same but without debugging it works fine, it only crashes when the debugger is attached and I am stumped.

I have recently installed a few additional extensions to Visual Studio 2010 before which this did not happen. They are:

- Python Tools for Visual Studio
- CodeMaid
- Javascript Parser
- NuGet Package Manager

I couldn't find any setting that could help me track down the problem. Is there a way to print out some more information from Visual Studio 2010 about what it is actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by uninstalling your plugins, one by one, and trying to reproduce the bug after each. If you get through all of the plugins and can still reproduce the bug, then reinstall visual studio. If the bug still happens, then preform a full check of your RAM for defects.